# Monzo Business Account payments

Tags: united-kingdom

Evening. Quick question realting to Monzo Business Accounts and making a payment from them. I have somebody who has one of these business accounts wanting to buy goods from me. They want bank account details (standard) as well as an email address (not standard) as well to complete the payment. This has obviously started alarm bells ringing as I have a business bank account with a standard bank and have never needed somebody's email address when making a payment. It smells of a scam to me where the person will use the email address supplied to request a change of password etc. Anybody care to enlighten me ref. this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As e-mail is not required for making a bank transfer, you can give them a new one - just register new account on gmail/hotmail/etc. Trow away the account once you are done working with this business.

Comment: Some bank transfer systems (especially from the more recent players in the field) will let you provide an e-mail when doing the transfer to "notify" the recipient. This is usually optional. Other payment systems will use an e-mail (or phone number) to initiate a transaction, but those will not need bank details.

Answer (score 3):

The Monzo [help pages](https://monzo.com/help/payments-getting-started/bank-transfer-how-to) do not mention needing an email address - just your name, sort code and account number as you would expect.

You might find this is the start of a social engineering scam where the buyer then decides they want to use a different method and need another piece of information from you, so over the conversation they build up enough info to hack an account. Or, as you say, it could just be that they want to try using your email address to hack directly.

Additionally, if whatever you are selling is on one of the well-known sellers' platforms (eBay, Amazon Marketplace, Etsy etc) then for them to try to pay you outside of the platform is also suspicious, and would remove any seller protection that you otherwise would have had.

Either way, it doesn't sound legit. I would suggest deleting the messages, blocking them and moving on.